# Error Uploading Images from SharePoint Image Library into a Blog Page

Tags: 2013, error, blog

I was wondering if anyone experienced the same issue.  I have a Blog page that allows users to successfully 'create new posts'...etc.  There are three choices to add images to the blog.  The user can upload 'by computer', 'by address', and 'by sharepoint'.  If the user uses 'by sharepoint'  it produces a error message (w/correlation id). If the user uses any of the other two options an image is successfully added.  Can anyone help with this issue?  Thank you!

Comment: did you check the ULS logs for the correlaion Id, what error basically sharepoint throwing?
are user uploading images from the picture library of the Blog Sites or from different location
Actually..when you create a blog sites, it create couple of libraries along with i.e categories , pictures.....
User should add images from the picture library.

Comment: Hi @Wasqas Sarwar MCSE - SharePoint is throwing an "Sorry, something went wrong " error.  When the user selects "add new post" within the 'body' the user selects pictures>from sharepoint.  When the user selects "from sharepoint" the error message appears.  However, this error message does not appear if the user selects 'from computer' or 'from address".

Comment: that's fine, but from what location of sharepoint user loading the pictures? is it picture library under the blog site or some where else?

Comment: Yes, it's a picture library under the blog site.

Comment: did you check the ULS logs for more detail about the error, as you mentioned error with correlation.

Comment: The log provided that the list feature is no longer available in the farm.

Comment: could you please share the logs, so that we get the trace and see which feature is not available.

Comment: Sure. ULS Log: "List feature is no longer available in the farm.  List is apart of the Knowledge Base - Knowledge Base List in SP2013." Thanks, @Wasqas Sarwar MCSE